# Clang Static Code Analyzer The result of the '>>' expression is undefined

Tags: c++, clang, static-analysis

I have a very simple code example that creates a perplexing result, at least to me, in the clang analyzer.

```
#include <random>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::mt19937 rng;
    std::vector<int> collection;
    std::shuffle(begin(collection), end(collection), rng);
}
```

"The result of the '>>' expression is undefined."

What does this mean and how do I fix it without simply using `#ifndef __clang_analyzer__` ?

The offending line is std::shuffle(begin(collection), end(collection), rng);

Then from `<algorithm> line 2840`

```
warning: The result of the '>>' expression is undefined
    __mask0_ = __w0_ > 0 ? _Engine_result_type(~0) >> (_EDt - __w0_) :
                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 1 warning generated.
```

Comment: Line number and if it's in a header file then some of the surrounding code would be useful.

Comment: I've added the additional information. Thanks!

Comment: If `_Engine_result_type` is a signed integer type then the result of `_Engine_result_type >> shift` is undefined. Ditto if `(_EDt - __w0_)` is out of range (`0..sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT-1`).

Comment: typedef _UIntType result_type; from the mersenne_twister_engine class implementation.  I would assume UIntType is unsigned?

Comment: One would hope so - how about the shift value ?

Comment: `static _LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR const size_t _EDt = numeric_limits<_Engine_result_type>::digits;

    size_t __w0_;

    __mask0_ = __w0_ > 0 ? _Engine_result_type(~0) >> (_EDt - __w0_) :
                          _Engine_result_type(0);
`
They appear to all be unsigned.

Comment: Yes, but could the shift value be out of range ?

Comment: I'm not sure how, considering there is nothing in the collection.